# iframe zoom w/ jquery

Tags: jquery, iframe, zooming

How can I zoom an iframe's contents by using cross browser jQuery? I know this can be done with the zoom css property from IE. Do gecko/webkit based browsers have a similar property?

Comment: probably need a bit more info - what are you zooming - a page or an image?

Answer (score 3):

There is a zoom plugin for jQuery here: http://css-tricks.com/examples/AnythingZoomer/

I think that works cross-browser too, which can solve not just your browser compatibility, but also save you a lot of code!